# Time inefficient code for my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written some code to go through an existing spreadsheet with a lot of data and set the background color of each cell according to its content. However I have about 80 rows and 200 columns and my code is far too slow. Can someone please help me understand how to make it more time efficient? Is there a better way?

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = 5;
    var lastRow = 80;
    var searchRange = sheet.getRange(3, 9, lastRow - 1, lastColumn - 1);
    //Loop through each column and each row in the sheet.
    for (i = 1; i < lastColumn; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < lastRow; j++) {
            var cell = searchRange.getCell(j, i);
            var cellValue = cell.getValue();
            var agentArray = splitTextEntry(cellValue);
            var agentName = agentArray[0]; //this gets the agent name from the cell entry
            var guestName = agentArray[1]; //this gets the guest name from the cell entry
            if ((cellValue === "") || (guestName === "")) {
                cell.setBackground("WHITE");
                cell.setValue("");
            } else {
                if (agentName === "UQ") {
                    cell.setBackground("#ff00ff");
                }
                if (agentName === "BCOM") {
                    cell.setBackground("#d5a6bd");
                }
                if (agentName === "GTR") {
                    cell.setBackground("#d9d2e9");
                }
                if (agentName === "FIT") {
                    cell.setBackground("#8e7cc3");
                }
                if (agentName === "AG") {
                    cell.setBackground("#0000ff");
                }
                if (agentName === "TU") {
                    cell.setBackground("#4a86e8");
                }
                if (agentName === "TG") {
                    cell.setBackground("#c9daf8");
                }
                if (agentName === "RA") {
                    cell.setBackground("#a2c4c9");
                }
                if (agentName === "AP") {
                    cell.setBackground("#00ff00");
                }
                if (agentName === "GI") {
                    cell.setBackground("#d9ead3");
                }
                if (agentName === "MMT") {
                    cell.setBackground("#b6d7a8");
                }
                if (agentName === "EXP") {
                    cell.setBackground("#f6b26b");
                }
                if (agentName === "CON") {
                    cell.setBackground("#f4cccc");
                }
                if (agentName === "TO") {
                    cell.setBackground("#ea9999");
                }
            }
        };
    };
    //forceRefresh(); //call
}
```

Comment: `splitTextEntry` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this:

1. Get data range;
2. Get bidimensional array of values of data range (getValues());
3. Get bidimensional array of backgroundColors of data range (getBackgrounds());
4. Iterate the array (iterate an change values from array is way faster!)
5. Apply you logic in the loop using values array and changing backgrounds array;
6. After the loop, set the new backgrounds Array to your data Range at once (.setBackgrounds(newBackgroundArray));

Answer (score 0):

```
function onMyOpen() {//probably needs to be installable
  const names=["UQ","BCOM","GTR","FIT","AG","TU","TG","RA","AP","GI","MMT","EXP","CON","TO"];
  const colors=["#ff00ff","#d5a6bd","#d9d2e9","#8e7cc3","#0000ff","#4a86e8","#c9daf8","#a2c4c9","#00ff00","#d9ead3","#b6d7a8","#f6b26b","#f4cccc","#ea9999"];
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var v=rg.getValues();
  var c=rg.getBackgrounds();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      let t=c.split(',');//had to guess at this since that function was undefined in your example
      let a=t[0];
      let g=t[1];
      if(!a || !g) {//this will fail if you don't have a
        c[i][j]="#ffffff";
        v[i][j]='';         
      }else{
        c[i][j]=colors[names.indexOf(a)];//you may need to trim a
      }
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(c);
  rg.setValues(v);
}
```